# I need help writing a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Now do I update several tables with columns that store social security number as a single transaction? I have over 70 tables to update the ssn with correct ssn.

The update is strictly by request. Occasionally, I get calls for a customer who entered their ssn wrongly the first time they registered on the our website. when I get such a request, I manually update all the ssn in every database table that stores information about the customer. A very tedious task to update over 70 tables with ssn columns one by one. Does anyone have an idea how to do this efficiently ?Can someone show me how write a stored procedure that I can pass in the old SSN and the new SSN then it updates the 70 tables accordingly?

Does anyone have a blue print that demonstrates how to write the stored procedure?

```
TableName  ColumnName
table1      colA
table2      colB
table3      colC
table4      cold
```

I query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view to retrieve all the tables that have ssn columns as shown above.

Comment: If you have SSN in 70 tables then you don't have a normalized database.  SSN should only be in one place.

Comment: In addition to what Blam said, without seeing your data structures, it's pretty impossible to write a specific query; just Google "tsql stored procedure update table" for syntax.

Comment: SSN is personally identifiable information.  This really should be separated from other data, encrypted and as Blam says, stored in once place.  And people wonder why data theft at Target, sony, Home Depot and other businesses are big news...  70 tables 70 changes to steal identity...

Comment: i totally agree with all of you. The place i currently work has a database that is poorly designed. its a mess and pain in the butt to deal with such a database.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the updates in a transaction. If you're changing a SSN in multiple tables, then you will want all tables updated, or none. I imagine that a "partially successful" update would have negative consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multiple stored procedures if they already exist or you can write the update script for each table in a new stored procedure, similar to this structure.

```
DECLARE @OldSSN VARCHAR(9) = "00000000",
        @NewSSN VARCHAR(9) = "00000001"

UPDATE TableName1
SET SSN = @NewSSN
WHERE SSN = @OldSSN

UPDATE TableName2
SET SSN = @NewSSN
WHERE SSN = @OldSSN
```

As Blam mentioned, it isn't good practice to have the SSN listed in more than 1 table for precisely this reason. It would be better to have a single Client table with the SSN and then use the newly created ClientId in all other tables.

Comment: You would want to transaction this sort of code, otherwise in the case of any errors you could end up with some tables updated and some that weren't.

Comment: Good call, not sure the best syntax for a rollback on multiple updates though.

Comment: Your code is now dangerous. It gives the illusion of checking for errors, but @@error only tells you what happened on the last statement executed. So in your example, if the first update failed, and the second worked, then you would not be rolling back the transaction. I suggest that you look at TRY..CATCH blocks, and XACT_ABORT.

Comment: Thanks, will remove the rollback portion

Answer (score 0):

Use this to generate all your updates. You may need to tweak the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
    'UPDATE [' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + TABLE_NAME + '] SET [' + Column_Name + ']=@NewSSN WHERE [' + Column_Name + ']=@OldSSN;'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE Column_Name ='SSN'
```

1. Create a stored procedure that accepts @OldSSN and @NewSSN as parameters.
2. Paste in the SQL above.
3. Wrap in a transaction